# Adding a unique check, without adding the unique constraint on the database level using spring boot and mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am working on an application and need to maintain a "topic" entity. The entity contains the following fields- id, text, and status(for deleted/active). For example, if we talk about news, a topic can be understood as a broad-level identifier used for the segregation of news. In order to publish a news, it must be assigned a topic. I am using soft-delete feature for deleting a topic from the database. Additionally, I want each topic to be unique. I am using the unique constraint on the database level, on the 'text' attribute in the table.

In case, some publisher adds a topic in his topic's list, but deletes it later on. Then he changes his mind again and thinks to have that topic in the topics list. The unique constraint on the database level will restrict the user from adding that topic even if it is deleted. One way to resolve this issue is to add a composite unique constraint- considering the 'text' as well as 'status' together. This leads to another scenario, if a user wants to delete the topic which he has added again, he won't be able to delete that.

Is there any way to add the unique constraint on the text, without adding any uniqueness constraints on the database level?

P.S. I don't want to perform hard delete at any cost.

Comment: Have you considered whether you could, in the case of a duplicate topic creation, simply undelete the previous topic?  Whether that would work depends on relational data you haven't discussed here (like should the tags be gone etc).

Comment: It is not possible to undelete the previous topic because some attributes in that entity will be used for auditing purposes. Undeleting them would require setting them to their default values again. This will lead to loss of data.

Comment: If you could handle "deleted" as `null` you could have the 2 column unique constraint you described, since null is never considered a duplicate.

Comment: Might you want to "undelete" the entry and update the columns?  See IODKU or REPLACE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the 'requirements' adequately, I recommend the "history-current" pattern.  This involves 2 tables:

- `History`:  append-only history of every change that occurs.  This is useful for "audit", etc.  There could be multiple rows per item -- initial insert; soft delete; un-delete, etc.
- `Current`:  One-row-per-item table of active items.  The bulk of the queries would touch only this table

Some actions would need to touch both tables.

- What you have as a soft-delete today would become one `iNSERT INTO History` plus one `DELETE FROM Current`.
- Undelete would need `INSERT INTO current SELECT ... FROM History...` plus `INSERT INTO History`

Comment: Yeah, that would be feasible.